# How to write dynamic header in DAX for Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I have two slicers and report header should display data based on selected values in a slicer. 
I was able to write an expression for single value selected, but is any way to write it for multiple values?

```
Header = 
    var selectyear =  SELECTEDVALUE(dim_Date[Year]) 
    var refreshdate = VALUES(fact_Premium[RefreshDate])
    var datetype = VALUES('Date Type Slicer'[Date Type])
    return "Report Period: " & selectyear & " As Of: " & refreshdate & " PST by " & datetype
```

[image]

---

For multiple values, if more than 1 year selected, let's say 2016, it should be:

**"Report Period 2016 - 2018 As Of 6/4/2018 10:09:36 PST by Accounting Date"**

How would I modify the expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple consecutive years selected, you could define a max year and a min year.

```
Header = 
    var minyear = MIN(dim_Date[Year])
    var maxyear = MAX(dim_Date[Year])
    var refreshdate = VALUES(fact_Premium[RefreshDate])
    var datetype = VALUES('Date Type Slicer'[Date Type])
    return "Report Period: " & minyear & " - " & maxyear & " As Of: " & refreshdate & " PST by " & datetype
```

Comment: Thank you !   I own you sooo much beer :)